# Script or command to check whether user used password to logon Windows machine

Tags: windows-10, command-line, passwords, shell-script

Is there a way to check whether a user uses a password to log in to his notebook vs. some other authentication method? I'd prefer to do this using a script. And maybe someone was using glpi.

Comment: Please provide some context examples?

Comment: Please specify what you mean by "usage"!

Comment: As my know, windows will not store password as the clear-text, the password would be stored by using 2 different password representations, generally known as "hashes". So it is not available to obtain a readable password.

Comment: I dont need user password, I just want to know that he has one.

Comment: What does *And maybe someone was using glpi.* mean? Please [edit] your question to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable logon auditing to have Windows track which user accounts log in and when.

You need first to enable Logon Auditing :

- Run `gpedit.msc`
- drill down to *Local Computer Policy > Computer Configuration > Windows Settings > Security Settings > Local Policies > Audit Policy*
- In the right-hand pane, double-click "Audit logon events"
- Enable the "Success" option to log successful logon attempts,
  "Failure" to log failed logon attempts.
- Click OK

You can view these events using Event Viewer :

- Start the Event Viewer
- Navigate to *Windows Logs > Security*
- Event ID 4624 represents successful login events
- Double-click an event to see its details :

[image]

Comment: Does event 4624 indicate the authentication method used to logon?

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator: I checked and haven't seen any. I uploaded an example of the available details [here](https://pastebin.com/r90Ysjwr).

Comment: In case anyone else stumbles on this like I did, you can look up the "LogonType" in the event details. The reference for integer value is here 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/securing-privileged-access/reference-tools-logon-types